# iOS MapClustering: CCHMapClusterController: Problems when zooming out after zooming in. Single annotations show cluster-annotation callouts

Tags: ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am trying out this new awesome library for annotation clustering called `CCHMapClusterConroller`. 
I reckon there is little or no help to get here, since the library is so new, but I'll give it a shot.

I am having trouble with the annotation callouts and I do not know what I am doing wrong.
When I enter my view controllers view, the annotations are clustered perfectly. 
When I then zoom in on my annotations they are declustered as expected.

However, when I zoom back out and the annotations starts to group up to clusters again, some clusters have the image of a single annotation. The same thing goes for their callouts. They have the titles and subtitles of my clustered annotations, but they have the disclosure button which i have only assigned to single, unclustered annotations.

This is how I initialize my cluster controller:
...

```
// viewDidLoad

    self.mapClusterController = nil;
    self.mapClusterController = [[CCHMapClusterController alloc]     initWithMapView:self.mapView];
    self.mapClusterController.delegate = self;
    self.mapClusterController.cellSize = 25;
    self.mapClusterController.marginFactor = 0.4;
//
...
```

This is how i populate the controller with my own custom annotations:

```
//...

[self.mapClusterController removeAnnotations:[self.mapClusterController.annotations     allObjects] withCompletionHandler:nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrayWithAnnotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    FFMapAnnotation *annotation;
    for(FFPlace *place in self.searchResult){
        annotation = [[FFMapAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotation.title = place.placeName;
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.placeLatitude,     place.placeLongitude);
        annotation.place = place;
        annotation.subtitle = place.placeAddress;
        [arrayWithAnnotations addObject:annotation];
    }
    [self.mapClusterController addAnnotations:arrayWithAnnotations     withCompletionHandler:nil];
//...
```

Now, I do believe that these two methods work correctly.
I imagine that the problem lies within the viewForAnnotation method.

This is currently how it looks:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id     <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView;

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:CCHMapClusterAnnotation.class]) {
    static NSString *identifier = @"clusterAnnotation";

    annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView) {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    } else {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }

    CCHMapClusterAnnotation *clusterAnnotation = (CCHMapClusterAnnotation *)annotation;
    clusterAnnotation.delegate = self;
    if(!clusterAnnotation.isCluster){
        FFMapAnnotation *annot2 = (FFMapAnnotation*)clusterAnnotation.annotations.allObjects[0];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[DefinedCategories getCategoryInformationForID:annot2.place.placeMainCategoryID].mapImage];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView.tag = -1;
    }else {
        return nil;
    }

}

return annotationView;
}

// the return nil at the end makes the annotation view a regular MKPinAnnotationView, which I use to visually represent my clusters.
```

Finally, the two delegate methods for cluster title and subtitle looks like this:

```
- (NSString *)mapClusterController:(CCHMapClusterController *)mapClusterController     titleForMapClusterAnnotation:(CCHMapClusterAnnotation *)mapClusterAnnotation
{
    NSString *title;
    if(mapClusterAnnotation.annotations.count > 1){
        title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld %@", (unsigned long)      mapClusterAnnotation.annotations.count, [AppDelegate get:@"PLACES"alter:nil]];
    } else{
        FFMapAnnotation *annotation =  mapClusterAnnotation.annotations.allObjects[0];
        return annotation.title;
    }
    return title;
}    

- (NSString *)mapClusterController:(CCHMapClusterController *)mapClusterController     subtitleForMapClusterAnnotation:(CCHMapClusterAnnotation *)mapClusterAnnotation
{
    NSString *title;
    if(mapClusterAnnotation.annotations.count > 1){
        title = [AppDelegate get:@"ZOOM_FURTHER"alter:nil];
    } else{
        FFMapAnnotation *annotation = mapClusterAnnotation.annotations.allObjects[0];
        return annotation.subtitle;
    }
    return title;
}
```

**What i want:**

[image]
[image]

**What is happening:**

[image]

Am I missing something vital in the delegate methods? I spent all day debugging this.

**EDIT:**
Adding the delegate method

```
- (void)mapClusterController:(CCHMapClusterController *)mapClusterController willReuseMapClusterAnnotation:(CCHMapClusterAnnotation *)mapClusterAnnotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [_mapView viewForAnnotation:mapClusterAnnotation];
    if(!(mapClusterAnnotation.annotations.count == 1)){
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_icon_button_thing"];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
    }else {
        FFMapAnnotation *annotation = mapClusterAnnotation.annotations.allObjects[0];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[DefinedCategories getCategoryInformationForID:annotation.place.placeMainCategoryID].mapImage];
    }
}
```

solved my issues!